# Python 2 script in Django 3

Tags: python, django, compatibility

I have a script that uses a library that is not available in python 3. I used the answer (execnet) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863832/calling-python-2-script-from-python-3/44965570) to call the python 2 script X from a python 3 script Y. This works fine without any problem. I added both scripts to the directory of the Django app I want to use script X in. Testing script Y still works. Importing script Y to be called from views.py works. Calling the function in Y form views.py works. But now script Y does not find script X anymore.

The Django error says `ImportError: No module named X`

If I add the script n the settings.py script to `INSTALLED_APPS` I get

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'X'`.

Is there an easier way to run a python2 script from django 3?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing this, but if you're **really** up the creek:

- create a Python 2 `virtualenv` for your Python 2 script called something like `py_env`
- install the package you need into `py2_env`

Then, in the view (which is running Python 3+ and Django 2+):

```py
from subprocess import check_output
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "my_app/my_template.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["program_output"] = check_output(
            "source /path/to/py2_env/bin/activate && /path/to/py2_script.py",
            shell=True,
        ).decode("utf-8")
        return context
```

This example will run the Python 2 script from the view and put the output of the program into the context as `program_output`. Good luck!