# Python3 import error: No module named 'rpm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos7

On a CentOS 7 I have installed python3 with the following command:

```
yum install -y python3
```

However, when I call `import rpm`, I get this error:

```
File "\<stdin>", line 1, in \<module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpm'
```

So how do I import the python3 rpm module?

Running `rpm --version` returns

```
RPM version 4.11.3
```

Accessing python (2.7.5) and running the import command works. So I could call a python2 script from python 3, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863832/calling-python-2-script-from-python-3) but this just feels wrong.

There are similar questions to this but they all relate to the rpm module being unavailable from Python2 and I don't have that problem. None deal with making the rpm module available in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the rpm python package for the python3 distribution?

```
pip3 install rpm-py-installer
```

Per the [homepage of RPM](https://github.com/junaruga/rpm-py-installer) this seems to be a required step.

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error stating: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-df6b5wx8/rpm-py-installer. I found a suggestion to run 'pip3 install --upgrade setuptools'. But the error persists when I run the command again.